# Error #1034 with a hit test object

Tags: flash

I got problem :  I did public class called "punkty". And here is script for this :

```
    package
    {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        public class punkty extends MovieClip
        {

            public function punkty() : void
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i created my player called just player. I want to do function : when player hit class type punkty do somethink. So i made script in layer in flash file :

```
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, punkty);
    function punkty(evt:Event){
            if(player.playerex.hitTestObject(punkty)){
                    score_number = (score_number + 1)
            }
    }
```

playerex is just box in player move clip. Now here my problem starts. Flash shows me error #1034 says that  cant be converted to flash.display.DisplayObject. Any ideas how to fix it ? And Im sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a function punkty and (think you also have) an object punkty in the same scope. You can't hit test on a function. I think you probably have strict mode off, or you would see a compiler error. This is why you should always have it on--when something breaks, you have a much better idea why.